# ObjectBox toMany List

Tags: one-to-many, objectbox

I have two entities connected with a One-to-Many relation and I want to have the whole List of the elements.
I tried:

```
int count = showcase.notices.size();
List<Notice> notList = showcase.notices.subList(0, count);
```

the `sublist` definition says `sublist(int start, int end)` where the `end` is not part of the list.
There is a more direct way to obtain the whole list?
Someting like

```
List<Notice> notList = showcase.notices.getList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `showcase.notices` is already a List.

Comment: Excuse me. I saw the definition "ToMany<Notice>" and don't try to get it as "List<Notice>".